# Как перехватить текст "файл не выбран" из элемента input type=file?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

В DOM он не появляется.

Делаю кастомную кнопку input type=file.

```
.form-item.form-type-managed-file.form-item-field-attachments-und-0 .file-widget.form-managed-file{
    position:relative;
}
.form-item.form-type-managed-file.form-item-field-attachments-und-0 .file-widget.form-managed-file input[type='file']{
    opacity:0;
}
.form-item.form-type-managed-file.form-item-field-attachments-und-0 .file-widget.form-managed-file #fake_upload_button{
    background-image:url(../images/button_file_upload.png);
    background-position:center left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    height:21px;
    width:80px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:2px;
}
```

Если пользователь выберет файл, нужно изменить текст "файл не выбран" на что-нибудь другое. Желательно на текст, выводимый браузером, так как сайт будет многоязычным.

Объясняю: мне нужно перехватить строку с именем файла, загружаемого через форму input type=file. Как я уже понял это возможно только на стороне сервера. Пока что я реализовал это так:

```
if($('#fake_upload_button').size() < 1){
    $('.form-item.form-type-managed-file .file-widget.form-managed-file').prepend('<span id="fake_upload_button" />');  
}
$('#fake_upload_button').empty();
$('#fake_upload_button').text('no file selected');
$('.form-item.form-type-managed-file .file-widget.form-managed-file input[type=file]').bind('change', function(){
    $('#fake_upload_button').empty();
    $('#fake_upload_button').text('file selected');
});
```

То есть в случае загрузки файла я просто меняю текст fake button

Comment: А где хотите менять этот текст? И зачем вы так старались, показывая CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мде... Может чего-то не понимаю, но если по пунктам:

> 1.мне нужно перехватить строку с именем файла

В общем, правильно. Только вместо **bind()** используем **on()**:

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change', function(){
    var fileName = $(this).val(); // имя файла
});
```

**.empty()** - лишнее, т.к. пользователь не выберет "пустоту"

> 2.Как я уже понял это возможно только на стороне сервера

JavaScript выполняется на стороне клиента!

> 3.То есть в случае загрузки файла я просто меняю текст fake button

С этим, я думаю, что проблем не возникнет ;)